# Which Afghans is Pakistan deporting?

Tags: immigration, pakistan, afghanistan, deportation

There [are](https://www.theguardian.com/global-development/2023/jan/10/pakistan-sends-back-hundreds-of-afghan-refugees-to-face-taliban-repression) about 250,000 Afghans who arrived in Pakistan since 2021. And [about](https://euaa.europa.eu/news-events/euaa-publishes-report-afghan-refugees-pakistan) 3 million in total, including those who arrived earlier. According to the first source, Pakistan has recently began deporting 600-800 Afghans per day. I'm curious whom is given priory in these deportations?